# How to exlude posts that have certain meta_value?

Tags: meta-query

I want to exclude some posts from the home page. So I want to use meta data, and filter all posts that are signed by meta_value=0.
Like this:

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page'=>28,
'meta_query' => array(
array(
    'key' => 'show_on_home',
    'value' => '0',
    'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
    )
)                   
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So, if I sign some post with meta_key=0 it will not apear.
The problem is that I have a lot off posts that don't have meta data at all, and I don't want to filter them.

Comment: You could reverse the logic and query posts that have meta key 'show_on_home' + meta value '1'

Comment: @diggy, A lot of posts don't have meta data at all, so I can not do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress 3.5 and up supports `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` comparison operators.

> compare (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are '=', '!=',
>   '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN',
>   'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' (only in WP >= 3.5), and 'NOT EXISTS' (also
>   only in WP >= 3.5). Default value is '='.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

So...

```
array(
    'key' => 'show_on_home',
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
)
```

... should show all posts that don't have that key. I think that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! to inckude posts that have value=1 on this key, I use this code: `$args = array(
        'posts_per_page'=>28,
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
         'key' => 'show_on_home',
         'value' => '0',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
         ),
        array(
         'key' => 'aa_show_on_home',
         'value' => '1'         
         ) 
        )
            
       );
       $query = new WP_Query( $args );`

Comment: Yes, but if you don't have too many with that '1' value, you'd get better performance by resetting that value and doing without that extra condition. `OR`s are not very efficient. Just something to consider.

Comment: Yes. I cheked it. it took 0.32 seconds vs 0.12 second without `OR`. Thank you very much!